# Add 1 to database record by clicking on HTML link

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, django-models

I want to track how many clicks each link gets and want this to be stored in the database here under the courses model:

https://github.com/justdjango/video-membership/blob/master/courses/models.py

Line 9 specifically (will loop through multiple links) is the link I would like to track the number of clicks for:

https://github.com/justdjango/video-membership/blob/master/courses/templates/courses/course_list.html

Each time a course title link is clicked from that loop or if a specific course slug from course_detail.html page is accessed (example - /courses/course_slug) after clicking that link, add 1 to a record called page_views.

I added this line to models.py Course class:

visited_times = models.IntegerField(default=0)

And I added 'visited_times' to admin.py list_display and fieldsets variables.

Here is some code but I am not sure if it is correct or how to implement it:

```
def get(*args, **kwargs) :
    response = super().get(*args, **kwargs)
    self.object.visited_times += 1  # this doesn't avoid race condition, but it's good enough for the sake of example
    self.object.save
    return response

MyModel.objects.filter(pk=self.object.pk).update(visited_times=F('visited_times') + 1)
```

Comment: Try to post relevant code snippets or reduced code version of the problem you are facing. This is helpful for whoever is looking at the problem.

Comment: @Anakin I am actually unsure how to begin something like this. All I know is you would do something like this: In the html make a javascript function that is triggered "on click".  This function will make an AJAX call to your view. Make a view that handles such request. or use the django activity stream but I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: @Anakin here is some code I have but I am not sure where to put it or what to do with it. def get(*args, **kwargs) :
    response = super().get(*args, **kwargs)
    self.object.visited_times += 1  # this doesn't avoid race condition, but it's good enough for the sake of example 
    self.object.save
    return response